# Page source contains an http item that makes page insecure; but in php files it's written as https!

Tags: headers, https

I can't seem to figure this out! I set up my site (https://goinspire.com/secure-payment/) to be https, but instead of the lock symbol I see a warning symbol. According to http://www.whynopadlock.com/ the issue is a certain url in the header ( http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js). I changed header.php to have that url as https ( https://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js), but for some reason it's not updating the page source.

here's the applicable line of header.php:

```
    <script src="https://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: This seems to be an issue in Firefox - in Chrome the lock symbol shows, but in Firefox there is a warning symbol instead.

UPDATE 2: I commented out the above php line, and the issue is gone. Now I just have to hope that it wasn't important (I think it wasn't)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: When people -1 a question it would be nice if they would tell me why, so I can adjust it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a cache issue, from my end everything work fine, I have the padlock, and when I look to the source, it show https. Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is very interesting! I'm testing on 2 computers, and on both, I see the lock icon in Chrome and the warning symbol in Firefox. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's written in https, but the file 302 redirects to http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js

also, in malsup's github for [cycle 2 his instructions](https://github.com/malsup/cycle2) clearly state

> `<!-- include Cycle2 -->`
>   `<script src="http://path/to/your/copy/of/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>`

So whatever you're using that requires Cycle2 to function properly now isn't, but you could just install your own copy of the file (as malsup's instructions explain).